# Ordenar una lista de listas

Tags: c#

Muy buen día a todos
Tengo una lista que contiene listas de strings
cada lista interna contiene un numero indefinido de strings provenientes de un grid, en el que no se cuantas columnas tiene, cada lista vendría siendo un renglón de ese grid, lo que necesito es ordenar las listas ascedentemente en base a un indice (que seria un string) que se me da.

```
List<List<string>> ls = new List<List<string>>();
List<string> li = new List<string>();
for(int i= 0; i < grid.RowCount; i ++)
{
    for(int j= 0; j < grid.ColumnCount; j++)
    {
        li.Add(grid[i, j].Value.ToString();
    }
    ls.add(li);
    li.Clear();
}
//este seria la posicion del dato por el que tengo que ordenar la lista
int index = x;
```

Me podrian ayudar a encontrar la manera mas eficiente de lograr el ordenamiento? Saludos

Comment: Seria interesante que mostraras el metodo que intentaste. Pero ya de por si, tu codigo tiene un problema. Estas agregando siempre la misma lista (li) a todos los "renglones" de la lista ls. Tenes que crear una nueva lista en lugar de hacer li.clear. recorda que li es un puntero a una lista, o sea que hacer clear limpia, por mas que la hayas agregado a otra lista

Answer (score 0):

Puedes ordenar usando [`OrderBy`](https://docs.microsoft.com/es-es/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.orderby?view=netframework-4.8):

```
var ordenada = ls.OrderBy(palabras => palabras[0]).ToList();
```

Deberás reemplazar el `0` por el índice de la columna sobre la que quieras ordenar. Puedes ver un ejemplo del código funcionando en <kbd>[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##fZJNb9NAEIbP9q8Y@WSLYiFxDESCIuXSkEpBQqLqYbqZhpF2d8zM2lCq/Paw61AElcjFmo9n35n1u85eOnPH42gc97B9sERhUf@d9ZfiPbnEEq1fUSRl94y44vhtUdfOoxlcq@wVAzzWlSVM7GAS3sEaObaWNB@7uQXUvXUFqSZU8AZvIdJ3uGJLb@bPdiaXy0wUqvrT/d14hOZduBs9OsbmApovqD9xQFX2fi6syUt0LCXechg8FxIOF/9RW6kkMjfzm8BRbA6vcRwoq4aTUEl8vtQkZ6Q2mmRXhs@LrDiSk4CWTvkaf7CX@7K4PyOyJpNBEobTqQ@cDcCYFB3Fc8M/js6TJN4VKDOHbExVcUzgxI8hYv7Vr@favSih@wptsWACjtmHfqM70vcP7YAe7xSzMUt4im9e3Xb9JykD2657cuYfGSsyU@lV1WV@MOKp/6ycqDV4AQ003aJ@3sqvh9q5nvc91Ifj8Rc)</kbd>.